# CasperJs Catch Timeout and Restart Process

Tags: coffeescript, event-handling, phantomjs, casperjs

**Question:** How to restart a casperjs process on a tiemout error

**Problem**
I run a crawler which sometimes times out:

```
[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
Error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('#identify tbody tr:nth-of-type(' + (current * 2 + 2) + ') div.details>div').innerHTML')
```

**Not working solution**
I put all my casper script into a function which I want to restart on the timeout event:

```
runCasper = () ->

  console.log ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STARTING CASPER<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"

  #Starts Casper and Takes a Snapshot
  casper.start(url, () ->
    self = this
    this.viewport(1024, 768, ()->
      self.capture('screenshotsKv/start.png')
    )
  )


  #Iterate through all 
  .eachThen(plz, (response) ->
    lots of code


  .on( 'wait.timeout', (msg) ->
    this.echo( 'Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR' )
    log.aborted = log.aborted.concat(log.last + ' ' + new Date().toString())
    functionsFiles.saveLog(log)
    self.capture('screenshotsKv/' + log.last + ' ' + new Date().toString() + '.png')
    runCasper()
  )


  #Save all results into the database
  .run(() ->
    this.exit()
  )

#Starts Casper
runCasper()
```

I also tried `step.timeout` but both don't trigger the restart.

**Possible reasons (imho):**

- because the whole process terminates including the .on listener?
- the listener is wrong?
- the timeout is from phantom and the listener is limited to casperjs?

Comment: No, PhantomJS has nothing to do with the timeout. This can probably be done by setting `casper.options.exitOnError = false;` and then do your own error handling.

Comment: Note: Coffeescript is not supported anymore in PhantomJS 2 if you want to update at a later time. You can also transpile your scripts.

Comment: I use gulp to compile the coffescript. So you mean when I set `casper.options.exitOnError = false;` then s.th. like  `.on( 'error', (msg) ->... ` should work? Actually it wouldn't be that bad if the script not just continues, because in the case of this error, the crawl failed on a particular page. In that case runCasper starts on the last log entry (which is before the stop).

Comment: What I want to avoid is to have two processes running in parallel.

Comment: Where is the difference between `.on('error..`and the `onError` which is set when creating the object? See: https://gist.github.com/leplatrem/2310901

Comment: I don't know what the difference is, so usually I look into the code. It's easy to read, so can do the same.